# Load and update a locally JSON file by input text

Tags: javascript, php, json, file

I'm working on a project with a little CMS system where data gets loaded from a extern JSON file.

This data loads in perfectly, but then I'm trying to update the JSON with HTML input fields (like changing a title and stuff)

A little preview of the JSON File:

```
{
"title":"Homepage",
"paths": [{
    "path": [{
         "questions":"Home"
    }]
}]
}
```

This is the code that I have for the loading in:

```
$string = "file.json";
$jsonString = file_get_contents($string);
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$paths = $data["paths"];
```

And then there are some input fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="Update the title" />
```

So I just want to update some textfields and overwrite the JSON titles for example. Hope someone can help me.

PS: I know that SQL maybe was a better solution, but I received this from the client.

Comment: This article on sanitizing user input might be helpful: [Keeping Web Users Safe By Sanitizing Input Data](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/11/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/).  CJ Wurtz's answer uses json_encode which handles this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
// read the file like you did before
$string = "file.json";
$jsonString = file_get_contents($string);
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// update whatever fields you need to
$data["title"] = $_POST["title"];

// json_encode() and write back to the same file you read from
file_put_contents($string, json_encode($data));
```